# Need help parsing JSON with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have the JSON block below that I am trying to parse with PowerShell. What the JSON is for is to denote permissions that an AD group should be given on an Azure App Registration. An application will have multiple groups assigned to it and each group will have a unique set of roles (permissions). The full JSON file has several of these `application` blocks.

Basically, what I want to be able to do with PowerShell is to take the `application`, query Azure AD to get the application resource and then modify the resource to assign each group to the app with its roles using `New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment`.

Conventional thinking would be the I need a loop nested inside of a loop nested inside of a loop where the first loop grabs the `application` block, then the second loop grabs the `groupname` block and then the third loop grabs the array of `roles` for that group.

```
 "application": 
  [
    {
      "groupname": "adgroup1",
      "roles": [ 
        "Permission1",
        "Permission2",
        "Permission3",
        "Permission4",
        "Permission5",    
        "Permission6" 
      ]
    },
    {
      "groupname": "adgroup2",
      "roles": [ 
        "Permission1",
        "Permission2",
        "Permission4",
        "Permission5",    
        "Permission6" 
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What PowerShell version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started

```
$json = SomethingThatGetsJson | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.application | % {
   $data = $_
   Write-Host $data.groupname
   $data.roles | % {
      $role = $_
      Write-Host $role
   }
}
```

`%` is shorthand for `ForEach-Object` if you want to get some more details on that. `$_` is the element value in the current iteration of the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the JSON returned is valid you should use the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet, It will convert the JSON string in to a proper object you can dot walk through and run your other standard cmdlets against like `select`, `where`, `foreach` etc